# JavaScript - override a function with a function that contains async callbacks and still return original value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In JavaScript I want to override a function on an object, but still call the original function and return it's value. So I'd normally do something like this:

```
var render = res.render;

res.render = function() {
    doSomethingNew();
    return render.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

However, what if that override contains async callbacks that need to be fired first before calling the original function eg:

```
var render = res.render;

res.render = function() {
    var self = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var middlewares = getSomeMiddleware();

    return callNextMiddleware(middlewares, function() {
        return render.apply(self, args);
    });
};

function callNextMiddleware(middlewares, callback) {
    var middlewareFunc = middlewares.shift();

    if (middlewareFunc) {
        return middlewareFunc.call(function() {
            return callNextMiddleware(middlewares, callback);
        });
    }
    else {
        return callback();
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using a 'return' statement where required. I have one problem though, the 'middlewares' variable is an array of functions, each middleware function looks like this:

```
function myMiddleware(next) {
    performLongRunningAsyncDataAccess(function() {
        next();
    });
}
```

Because it doesn't use 'return next()' the return value of the original res.render method is never passed back. I can get this to work if I get all the middleware functions to use 'return next()', but they come from an external source so I have no control over them, I can only guarantee that they will call 'next()'.

A bit of background, this is a Node.js app. The middleware is basically Connect middleware, and I'm trying to override the Express.js res.render method.

Comment: which of those function is calling something asynchronous? Btw: I think it should be `return middlewareFunc.call(this, function()...)`

Comment: basilikum, the middleware functions themselves might do something asynchronous, e.g. select some records from a database, or hit the file system etc.

Comment: ok, and what exactly is it supposed to do? As it is right now, it looks like you want to loop through all the middleware function and at the very end call the render function? Or you probably call render first, get a bunch of middleware function, execute them all, then call render again?

Comment: Agreed with @basilikum. There's nothing seems asynchronous in this code. callback != asynchronous.

Comment: I've updated the example middleware. Hope it makes it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is a bad idea to mix asynchronous functions with `return` statements. Everything that you want to return, you can pass as arguments to your callback functions. So I still hope I understand your code correctly but I would assume, that you call the `render` function, which then grabs an array of `middleware` functions. Then you want to execute all the functions in that array, using the next as an callback to the previous. After all the functions have been executed, the `render` function should be called again, thus creating kind of an infinite loop. Assuming all of that, lets take a look at some of your `return` statements:

```
return middlewareFunc.call(function() {
    return callNextMiddleware(middlewares, callback);
});
```

The first `return` in this block is useless since `middlewareFunc` is asynchronous and will therefore most likely return `undefined`. The second `return` statement is also useless, since it returns from the function, that you use as callback. But since your callback is just called by using `next();`, the return value will never be used.

```
else {
    return callback();
}
```

In this block `callback` is the `render` function. So lets take a look at this function:

```
res.render = function() {
    var self = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var middlewares = getSomeMiddleware();

    return callNextMiddleware(middlewares, function() {
        return render.apply(self, args);
    });
};
```

So all last three `return` statements are essentially there, because you want to return something from your `render` function. But to be consistent, you should consider using a callback for that function as well:

```
res.render = function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var middlewares = getSomeMiddleware();

    callNextMiddleware(middlewares, function() {
        //this will be called after all the middleware function have been executed
        callback();
        render.apply(self, args);
    });
};
```

So basically you are getting rid of all the `return` statements and using pure asynchronous design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

`callNextMiddleware` should return its recursive call's return value, not `middlewareFunc`'s.

```
if (middlewareFunc) {
    var result;
    middlewareFunc.call(this, function() {
        result = callNextMiddleware(middlewares, callback);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWGXs

Comment: If the middleware does something asynchronous that takes a long time (such as perform a database operation), then 'result' returns undefined. I've updated your example http://jsfiddle.net/mWGXs/1/

Comment: Cleared now, but in my opinion there's no solution. To archive goal `render()` should wait before return until all callbacks are finished, but there's no way in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Mics, I thought this might be the case. Looks like I'm going to have to find a different approach.